# Get html table width to fit screen using Literal asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm building a html table dynamically in an ASP.NET code behind file using C#. I basically loop through a set of data which is an unknown number of records and split a string containing all the values to make the required number of tds. I display the html by assigning it to an asp:Literal control. However I can't get the table to fit the screen - the browser is adding a horizontal scroll bar and the full table is well off the screen. I tried in IE 8 and FF 3.6.13. Most things I've read online about it say to set the width to 100%. I'm doing this but it's having no effect. Does assigning html to a Literal control like this render the same as it would any other way? The aspx page has a master page and the front end code for the aspx page is:

**EDIT**: I've pasted the outputted html code here:
http://www.codepaste.net/nza7r8

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
    <div><br />
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal><br />
    </div>
    <div id="paging">
        <asp:Button ID="btnPrev" runat="server" Text="Prev" CssClass="niceInput" onclick="btnPrev_Click" Enabled="False" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" CssClass="niceInput" onclick="btnNext_Click" Enabled="False" />
        <asp:Label class="Grid" ID="lblPageNumber" runat="server"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label class="Grid" ID="lblTotalRecords" runat="server"/>
    </div><br />    
</asp:Content>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
List<string> errorColumnsList;

stringBuilder.Append("<table align='center' width='100%' style='border-style:inset'>");

//1st element is header so do this separately
stringBuilder.Append("<tr style='font-size:smaller; font-weight:bold'>");
stringBuilder.Append("<td>ID</td><td>Error type</td>");
errorColumnsList = new List<string>(items[0].HoldingsError.Split("||".ToCharArray()));

foreach (string str in errorColumnsList)
{
    stringBuilder.Append("<td>" + str.Trim() + "</td>");
}

stringBuilder.Append("</tr>");

//Continue on with the rest of the data - remove header first
items.Remove(items[0]);

foreach (HoldingsErrorItem item in items)
{
    stringBuilder.Append("<tr style='font-size:smaller'>");
    stringBuilder.Append("<td>" + item.HoldingsErrorID + "</td><td>" + item.ErrorType + "</td>");
    errorColumnsList = new List<string>(item.HoldingsError.Split("||".ToCharArray()));

    foreach (string str in errorColumnsList)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("<td>" + str.Trim() + "</td>");
    }

    stringBuilder.Append("</tr>");
}

stringBuilder.Append("</table>");

Literal1.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: I dont understand, you want that your table is resized in the visible screen?

Comment: I want the table to fit the screen. It's not fitting the screen and the browser is adding a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: But this is normal because if table is too long, browser is not able to do a personal resizing and fit table to screen. You need to manage css style like font size of anything else. if table is too long you i can suggest you to use pagination.

Comment: The table isn't too long it's too wide. I have pagination. I need to make the table fit the screen left to right, not top to bottom. Does this make sense?

Comment: Ok Carl, Sorry, now i understand. Try using width attribute inside style, ex. style="width=100%; border-style:inset" in the table.

Comment: Thanks - tried what you suggested but still the same unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `.Text` property of an asp:Literal to be a string of HTML will indeed end up treating the HTML for the table no differently to if it was explicitly in the page.

How many columns are there in the resulting table? Usually, if the table would be wider than the window, each table cell in HTML will wrap its content on space characters to reduce the table width to fit, until it's down to single words. Once it hits that point, it cannot wrap any further and it's irrelevant what width you set - it will be forced to be as wide as the total widths of the longest words in each column.

**Edit:** The demonstration page shows what I expected: a large number of columns and, although each is "shrink wrapped" to the minimum width possible (by wrapping content on whitespace), the total width is still large.

I'm afraid this is just how HTML tables work. I tried adding `style="max-width:3%;overflow:hidden;"` to each `td`, but even that doesn't stop the cells stretching to fit their longest unwrappable piece of content.

Comment: the table is 31 columns in total and one of the columns is quite a longish text value, approx 150 characters. The other column values would all be quite short, various numeric values and short text codes.

Comment: Hey @Matt I'm still having this problem. The outputted html is at http://www.codepaste.net/nza7r8 if you have time to take a look..cheers

Comment: @Ciaran Bruen - Sorry for the crazy late reply, I only just noticed that there was something in my inbox. Looking at your code, the problem is simply the amount of data you have in the table. Every single column is "shrink-wrapped" to the shortest possible width it can be, given the longest single string in any of its cells. It's wrapped every cell (can only wrap on whitespace) where it can, and cannot reduce the total width any further. Unfortunately, that leaves the table very wide, no matter what width you try to set. This is just how HTML tables work, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks @Matt that's the conclusion I eventually came to as well